# Getting - ERROR: could not get pipe properties while flashing my android AOSP

Tags: android, android-build

While flashing my device (Nexus S or Galaxy Nexus) with AOSP 4.1.2 I'm receiving the following error `ERROR: could not get pipe properties`. As a result it is unable to load the OS. However I googled a bit and tried to re-install adb (http://code.google.com/p/adb-fastboot-install/) and fastboot and it didn't work. And I'm using a MacBook with LION in it.

Any suggestion?

Comment: this is not a programming question

Comment: @tyczj untue - installation of a custom build of the android open source project *is* a "development question" as one cannot meaningfully do platform development if one cannot install the results (dev tools questions are explicitly on topic here)

Comment: If it is an off topic can you please suggest where should I post this?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when trying to unlock my Nexus 9 bootloader, and had to overcome two problems to get past this error:

1. Enable Developer Options
2. In Developer Options, Enable USB debugging
3. In Developer Options, Enable OEM unlock
4. Boot up the device normally
5. Terminal: `adb reboot bootloader`
6. Go into the `fastboot` menu item
7. Terminal: `fastboot oem unlock`

Steps 3 and 6 were the ones that were not explained in the developer docs.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue on my Mac Yosemite. In other blogs I read that this can be a power issue. My device was connected via USB to the keyboard. So I switched to the port on my MacBook and then I tried again. This fixed my error and my flash was successful.